# Jquery code not working, but JavaScript is. What is my error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The JavaScript that is commented out works, however, I need it in jQuery for mobile touch functions. So I tried to convert into jQuery, but it does not run properly. What this program does is calculate quadratic equations. Sorry for the bad variable names. What is my error? The webpage loads, but it when I press a button nothing happens.

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Quadratic Calculator</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css"> -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
      <style>
        .jumbotron {
          background-color: aliceblue;
        }

        body {
          background-color: aliceblue;
          font-family: sans-serif;
          color: black;
        }

        .equation {
          font-size: 1.75rem;
          background-color: aliceblue;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        h1 {
          text-align: center;
        }

        button {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 2em;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        input {
          width: 5rem;
        }

        #or {
          display: none;
        }

        #x2 {
          display: none;
        }

        .button-secondary {
          background: rgb(66, 184, 221);
          /* this is a light blue */
          color: white;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Quadratic Equation -->
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Quadratic Calculator</h1></div>
        <div class="jumbotron"> <input type="number" class="equation" name="a" id="a"> <span class="equation">x<sup>2</sup>+ </span> <input type="number" class="equation" name="b" id="b"> <span class="equation">x+ </span> <input type="number" class="equation" name="c" id="c">
          <span class="equation">= 0</span> <br> <br> <button id='submit' class="btn btn-success">Submit</button> <br> <br> <button id='clear' class="btn button-secondary">Clear</button>
          <h2 id='x1'>x=</h2>
          <h2 id="or">or</h2>
          <h2 id='x2'>x=</h2> </div>




      </div>





      <!--<script>
                var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
                var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
                function quadraticFunction() {
                    var or = document.getElementById('or');
                    var x2 = document.getElementById('x2');
                    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
                    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
                    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
                    var x1 = document.getElementById('x1');
                    if (a === null) {
                        a = 1;
                    }
                    var d = Math.sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c));
                    var answer1 = (-b - d) / (2 * a);
                    var answer2 = (-b + d) / (2 * a);
                    if (isNaN(answer1) && isNaN(answer2)) {
                        x1.innerHTML = "x = imaginary number";
                        or.style.display = "none";
                        x2.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        if (a == 0) {
                            x1.innerHTML = "This is not a quadratic equation!";
                        }
                        if (answer1 == answer2) {
                            x1.innerHTML = "x = " + answer1;
                            or.style.display = "none";
                            x2.style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            x1.innerHTML = "x = " + answer1;
                            x2.innerHTML = "x = " + answer2;
                            or.style.display = "block";
                            x2.style.display = "block";
                        }
                    }
                }


            var clearer = function() {
                var x1 = document.getElementById('x1');
                var x2 = document.getElementById('x2');
                var or = document.getElementById('or');
                x1.innerHTML = "x =";
                x2.style.display = "none";
                or.style.display = "none";
            }

            ;
            submit.addEventListener("click", quadraticFunction);
            clear.addEventListener("click", clearer);
                </script>-->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
        var submit = $("#submit");
        var clear = $("#clear");

        function quadraticEquation() {
          //Declaring variables 
          var or = $("#or");
          var x1 = $("#x1");
          var x2 = $("#x2");
          var a = $("#a").val();
          var b = $("#b").val();
          var c = $("#c").val();


          if (a == null) {
            a = 1;
          }

          var d = Math.sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c));
          var answer1 = (-b - d) / (2 * a);
          var answer2 = (-b + d) / (2 * a);
          if (a == 0) {
            x1.text(“This is not a quadratic equation!”);
            or.css(“visibility”, “hidden”);
            x2.css(“visibility”, “hidden”);
            return;
          }

          if (isNaN(answer1) && isNaN(answer2)) {
            x1.text(“x = imaginary number”);
            or.css(“display”, “none”);
            x2.css(“display”, “none”);

          } else {
            if (answer1 == answer2) {
              x1.text(“x = “+answer1);
              or.css(“display”, “none”);
              x2.css(“display”, “none”);
            } else {

              x1.text(“x = “+answer1);
              x2.text(“x = “+answer2);
              or.css(“display”, “block”);
              x2.css(“display”, “block”);

            }

          }
        }

        function clearer() {
          var or = $("#or");
          var x1 = $("#x1");
          var x2 = $("#x2");

          x1.text(“x = “);
          or.css(“display”, “none”);
          x2.css(“display”, “none”);

        }

        submit.on(“click”, function() {
          quadraticEquation();
        });

        clear.on(“click”, function() {
          clearer();
        });
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Check the quotation marks on your jQuery version, they look like they were copied from a source with "smart quotes" so they are not matching.

Comment: Does your jQuery code really have nonstandard quote marks like `‘ ’ “ ”` or is that an artifact of copying and pasting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: @PaulAbbott It was an artifact of copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pasted the code in from another source you transferred the single ticks, instead of single quotes:
`var submit = $(‘#submit’);` should be `var submit = $('#submit');`

Comment: Yeah, I kinda stopped there. :)

Answer (score 0):

In all your selections you have the back tick instead of quotes; fix that and see what you get

Comment: What is the difference between black ticks and single quotes?

Comment: they are different characters, they are from different buttons on the keyboard

Comment: They have different unicode values, and therefore the browser interprets them differently. `' (\u0027)` is not the same as `‘ (\u2018)`.